Effect of catapult field on the weight of magnets

Diagram shows a metal rod, PQ placed perpendicularly to two permanent magnets and connected to an electric circuit. The steel core containing the two magnets is placed on an electronic balance. What will happen to the electronic balance reading when the switch is turned on and the force acting on the wire is downward?
This is my thought, the downward force acting on the wire wouldn't contribute to any increase of weight because it's not placed on the balance. Meanwhile, a reaction force will act on the magnet and cause the decrease of weight.
But the answer given is the weight increase...Maybe the answer is wrong ? And one more question, what is the reaction force and how does it act on the magnet ?

Maybe you've just taken the opposite direction of the electric current (i.e. installed the generator in the opposite direction)

Hello! I have taken the liberty to resize your images to improve readability. Feel free to rollback if you wish. Thanks!
